# Is NSURL/CFURL's resource property cache per-object, or global?

Tags: nsurl

These methods/functions are used to access resource properties:

```
- [NSURL getResourceValue:forKey:error:]
- [NSURL resourceValuesForKeys:error:]
CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey()
CFURLCopyResourcePropertiesForKeys()
```

When called, property values are cached. The documentation (hidden away in `CFURL.h`) states that the `NSURL` methods will only cache the value for the duration of the current run loop cycle **if** called on the main thread. All other use cases will cache until explicitly cleared.

However, what I've been unable to hunt down any documentation for: is this cache on a per-object basis, or global?

Comment: I wish I knew. I've been noticing for a while that my code is more reliable if I insist file checking is done on the main thread, and I think this is the reason why. I have only just come across the comment buried within NSURL.h and it looks like this is why file statuses never change if viewed on any other thread. So much for GCD and multithreading helping you move file operations off the main thread! It'd be much easier if there was a way to switch this caching off, at least for individual URLs. But after searching, you're the only person I can see talking about this!

Comment: Oh, reading the CFURL.h comments, it seems it gives control over how you deal with the caching... There are two functions `CFURLClearResourcePropertyCacheForKey` and `CFURLClearResourcePropertyCache` that seem to work at the URL level... but it still doesn't answer whether this cache is held against each URL, or if there is a global pool. There are times I really wish Apple would put things like this in the actual docs, rather than buried deep in a .h file somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, `CFURL.h` is pretty illuminating, just not on this one thing I care about! Ah well.